# Gson: how to create adapter to remove quotation marks from String

Tags: javascript, java, gson

I am using `gson` to convert `Map` to the `JSON` structure. The thing is that there is no such type in `Java` to hold `javascript` function. I can't hold the function in `String` becouse `javascript` doesn't see it as a function! I have read that I can write my own adapter to configure `gson` in the way it will know how to deal with my object type. I have no idea how to start with it and I am looking for any pieces of advice. I better start with an example what I want to achieve. This is what I get:

```
"object": {
    "name": "sampleName",
    "func": "function() { doSomething(); }",
    "number": 2.0
}
```

this is what I want to achieve (function is without quotations):

```
"object": {
    "name": "sampleName",
    "func": function() { doSomething(); },
    "number": 2.0
}
```

Currently, I am storing functions in `Map` as a String. From this what I've read I have to options. Remove quotations from `String` or create my own type which will be similar to `String` (but here is another problem, `String` is immutable). Both solutions should be somehow done by an adapter which I need to create.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: `eval` on the JS side?

Comment: @RC. I tried `eval` it won't work because I am injecting this `JSON` into `WebView` from `Android` as a String, I can't do `javascript` stuff on it. It's all about conversion here